# Is it possible to create variables dynamically with Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I have the following problem:
I have to create Veiables like such:

```
var qrcode_1 = my_CreateQRcode(document.getElementById("qrcode_1"));
var qrcode_2 = my_CreateQRcode(document.getElementById("qrcode_2"));
var qrcode_3 = my_CreateQRcode(document.getElementById("qrcode_3"));
.....
```

The number of the variables can bie fom 1 to 60..
ist it possible to create these varibles   dynamically depending on the amount of actually needed variables..
of have I to degine 60 variables in the code?

Comment: Use arrays, that’s the case arrays exist for

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that? Ever heard of for-loops and arrays?

Comment: What if you have only 50 `qrcode` variables but you try to use `qrcode_60`? That would throw an error. And if you don't know how many there are, how would you know which identifiers to use - you won't be able to determine if there are 5 or 50 of them, if you merely have an unknown amount of variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array instead:

```
var qrcodes = Array.from(
  { length: 60 },
  (_, i) => my_CreateQRcode(document.getElementById('qrcode_' + (i + 1)))
)
```

But it would be better to use classes instead of numeric-indexed IDs, so you could do something like

```
var qrcodes = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.qrcode'),
  my_CreateQRcode // second argument to Array.from is a mapper function
);
```

Note that array-like structures are *zero-indexed*, not one-indexed, so, for example, `qrcodes[0]` will correspond to the first element found and sent through .`my_CreateQRcode`.

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you really need that many variables (as others pointed out, you really should use an array instead), this is how you can achieve that:

```
for (let i = 60; i > 0; i--) { 
  window["qrcode_"+i] = my_CreateQRcode(document.getElementById("qrcode_"+i)) 
};
```

**Please note that in this specific scenario this is overwriting the already existing variables (the browser automatically creates a global variable for each element with a unique id value under the name of that value, which holds a reference to that element).**

Answer (score 0):

You can create class for your html element.

Example:

```
In HTML->
    <div class="qrcode"></div>....<div class="qrcode"></div>
IN JS ->
    var qrcodes= document.getElementsByClassName(".qrcode");
    for(i=0;i<=qrcodes.length;i++){
           log(qrcodes[i]);
        }
```